# Replace NULL columns in live database with data from a SQL Server backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I recently had a horrible blunder.

While attempting to fix an issue we were having with our Exact Synergy system I was attempting to replace the data in two columns for one account with NULL, instead I replaced those two columns in ALL accounts with NULL. Completely restoring from a backup is not an option so now I am left trying to figure out how to replace the missing data.

I have made a full restore of a recent backup for this database to a test database and have confirmed that the data I need is there. I am trying to figure out how to properly write a query that will replace the data in the two columns.

Since this is a backup of the same database, the tables and columns are all identically named.

- The databases are `Synergy` and `Synergy_TESTDB`
- The owner of the tables is `dbo`
- The table is called `Addresses`
- The columns are called `textfield1` and `textfield2`

What I would like to do is take the data in `textfield1` and `textfield2` from the backup database and use it to populate the empty, or NULL, columns in the live database.

I am extremely new to SQL, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Sorry no, it was late and there was some time between posts so I went home, I am back now and looking into it.

Comment: what was your result?

Comment: @MitchWheat I had posted the results in response to your answer below, I still have not been able to get this to work. Oddly enough my mentions to you didn't seem to go through at the time, just now realizing that I shouldn't put spaces between your first and last names.

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously untested. I take no responsibility for you using this code. 
That said I'd like to try and help you.

The main point is the 3 part database.table naming: I'm assuming you restored backup to same server. I'm also assuming you have a primary key on the table? And that Synergy_TESTDB is the restored database:

```
update target 
set target.textfield1 = source.textfield1 
from Synergy.dbo.Addresses target
join Synergy_TESTDB.dbo.Addresses source on target.PrimaryKeyCol = source.PrimaryKeyCol
where target.textfield1 IS NULL

update target 
set target.textfield2 = source.textfield2 
from Synergy.dbo.Addresses target
join Synergy_TESTDB.dbo.Addresses source on target.PrimaryKeyCol = source.PrimaryKeyCol
where target.textfield2 IS NULL
```

(Sure it could be done in a single update, but I'm trying to keep it simple.)

I strongly suggest you try in another test database first.

A good habit to get in to is to use a pattern like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Perform updates

-- Examine the results: select * from dbo.Blah ...

-- If results are wrong, we just rollback anyway
ROLLBACK

-- If results are what you want, uncomment the COMMIT and comment out the ROLLBACK
-- COMMIT TRANS
```

Comment: I have entered the script as written and replaced PrimaryKey with the name of the keys for the textfield1 rows of both tables (PK_Addresses_1) but when I try to execute it tells me that it is an invalid column name, same text if I leave PrimaryKey as PrimaryKey. 

going to keep poking at it to see if I can figure out what I'm doing wrong, unless it's glaringly obvious to you. thank you very much for your help! I've been stuck on this all day!

Comment: if I use textfield1 instead of either PK_Addresses_1 or PrimaryKey it does not generate an error, but it also does not change any rows, hmm...

Comment: Don't use the name of the primary key 'PK_Addresses_1', use the name of the column that is the primary key, Like 'Id' for instance. Post the schema of the table please including the PK definition.

Comment: The column name that I have assigned the keys to in both databases at this time are textfield1, the Table_Schema for these are all dbo.

I have pulled this information by using the query
`select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='Addresses'`

When I use textfield1 in place of PrimaryKeyCol I do not receive any errors, but no rows are changed either, I thought maybe it would be a case sensitive issue so I also tried null and Null.

Comment: Sorry I just read that I need to mention you for you to get notifications.

Comment: I think what you mean by PK definition is what is represented in the Indexes/Keys properties box? 
`Columns - textfield1 (ASC) | Is Unique - Yes | Type - Primary Key | Name - PK_Addresses_1 | Create As Clustered - NO`